# What is the most efficient way to update the array values of an unordered_map for a specific key?

Tags: c++, arrays, variable-assignment, unordered-map, mapped-types

Consider the following unordered maps

```
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, int> str2int { 
        {"key1", 1},
        {"key2", 2}
    };
    str2int["key1"]++;
    str2int["key3"] = 5;

    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::array<int, 2>> str2arr { 
        {"key1", {1,2}},
        {"key2", {3,4}}
    };
}
```

Updating the values of `str2int` is straightforward as seen above.
What is the most efficient and cleanest value assignment method for the unordered_map `str2arr` for a given (existing or new) key?

Comment: I'd guess the best way is to do exactly the same as you would for the int. But usually if performance really matter you'll want to test & monitor various options on target system.

Comment: `str2arr["key1"][0] = 42;`

Comment: Yes! I was looking for this answer, which actually I tried before posting the question, but for some reason it didn't work at that time. Go figure! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for a compound literal if you want to add a new `std::array` value to the map.

```
str2arr["key3"] = (std::array<int, 2>){ 5, 6 };
```

[Suggested reading](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.2.0/gcc/Compound-Literals.html#:%7E:text=In%20C%2B%2B%2C%20a%20compound,temporary%20array%20to%20a%20pointer.) on the lifetime implications of using this in C++.

Comment: How about incrementing the first cell value of the array for "key1"? In this example, the arrays have only two elements. If they had 1000 elements, would you use the same method, i.e., replacing the entire array for updating only one array element? Isn't there a better way to do it?

Comment: Of course you wouldn't replace the entire array to update one element, but if you want to add a new array element to the map.